# How to print word document in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm using the following code. When I print from notepad it get printed. But when I print from  MS Word it get printed without words containing symbols. I think I have to enter doc format in code. How can I do this?

```
String content="";
   private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName;
        // Show the dialog and get result.
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            fileName = ofd.FileName;

            var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            //var document = application.Documents.Open(@"D:\ICT.docx");
             //read all text into content
            content=System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);
            //var document = application.Documents.Open(@fileName);
        }
    }
 private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        printDoc.DocumentName = "fileName";
        printDlg.Document = printDoc;
        printDlg.AllowSelection = true;
        printDlg.AllowSomePages = true;
        //Call ShowDialog
        if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
             printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);            
             printDoc.Print(); 
        }
    }
 private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
 {
   ev.Graphics.DrawString(content,printFont , Brushes.Black,
                   ev.MarginBounds.Left, 0, new StringFormat());
 }
```

Comment: Word documents are not plain text.  You can't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there are no basic functions which support reading the word format and / or printing it with the default Print Functionality in .net .

IF you just want to print the document without any further information you can start a basic windows print process by using the [Start method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0w4h05yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the  [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class with the **PrintTo** Verb

s. MSDN Forum  [Print Word Document in c#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fa0a3db8-3d3d-4536-b17e-4f0a305b123c/print-word-document-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)
Example form the linkes post:

```
using (PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog())
{
pd.ShowDialog();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\documents\filetoprint.doc");
info.Verb = "PrintTo";
info.Arguments = pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(info);
}
```

If you need to do more (layout, other data ...) you could write your own doc / docx parser or use something like the aspose tools

s. http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx

perhaps infragistics / devexpress may also components to read word documents, convert them to HTML or furthermore supporting direct printing of the word.

For all tools trial versions should be aviable

http://www.infragistics.com

https://www.devexpress.com/