# “Microsoft Print to PDF” printer for webBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, printing

I wont print in pdf file current page on webBrowser control,? its code:

```
 // generate a file name as the current date/time in unix timestamp format
    string file = (string)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds.ToString();
 // the directory to store the output.
    string directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

 // initialize PrintDocument object
    PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();

    doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
    doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
 // tell the object this document will print to file
    doc.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
    doc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = Path.Combine(directory, file + ".pdf");
    doc.Print();

     private void pd_PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
     {   
       webBrowser1.Navigate("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812996/
       programmatically-provide-a-filepath-as-input-file-for-microsoft-print-to-pdf-p");
     }
```

File genereted, but its empty....

Comment: Hi, could you please edit your post to let us know precisely what it is you're trying to achieve, and why the current code you've provided isn't working?

Comment: Did you find out any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try direct print method of web browser

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //webBrowser1.ShowPrintDialog(); //Printer Dialog will appear
        //webBrowser1.ShowPrintPreviewDialog(); //preview of the document
        webBrowser1.Print(); //directly print with current printer settings 
    }
```

Comment: webBrowser1.Print();  - In this case, a dialog box "save file" is showing, but I need to work in batch mode, I specify the file name programmatically

Comment: file name means printer document name??then what is the use of that

Comment: Yes. i have 1000 url in db, and i need make their screenshot in pdf format. Therefore, I need automatic saving, without user intervention