# Print vector image not pixel based to PDF using Microsoft Print To PDF printer

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I am trying to print a vector image (emf file) as a PDF using the default implemented Microsoft Print To PDF printer. Right now I just create the `PrintDocument`, change it's `PrinterSettings` to the chosen printer *Microsoft Print To PDF* and change other `PrintDocument`'s properties.

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);

pd.PrinterSettings = /*some custom printerSettings*/;
```

Now I basically just draw a scaled image of the emf file on a `Bitmap` which I draw afterwards on `pd`.

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap printDrawing = Draw.PrintVersion(); //custom method that handles the scaled drawing

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(printDrawing, new Point(0, 0));
}
```

In return I get a PDF file, but the issue is that the drawing on the PDf file is pixel based since I draw just a `Bitmap` on `pd`.

So the question is how can I solve this issue, so that the result is a PDF file which scales the vector image accordingly? So I have to skip the drawing, so I thought about just setting a filePath of the EMF file as an input for the `PrintDocument`, but neither [Programmatically provide a filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812996/programmatically-provide-a-filepath-as-input-file-for-microsoft-print-to-pdf-p) nor [How to programmatically print to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896952/how-to-programmatically-print-to-pdf-file-without-prompting-for-filename-in-c-sh) , helps me in any way, since they all focus just on drawing the content which will result again in a pixel based `PrintDocument`.

So how can I set just a file/filePath as an input to the `PrintDocument` to keep the vector information?