# How to programmatically print to PDF file in WPF using the "Microsoft Print To PDF" printer that comes with Windows 10?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, printing, windows-10

This question

[How to programmatically print to PDF file without prompting for filename in C# using the Microsoft Print To PDF printer that comes with Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896952/how-to-programmatically-print-to-pdf-file-without-prompting-for-filename-in-c-sh)

contains a good answer on how to achieve this in a Windows Forms application.

Unfortunately I use WPF and have not been able to find a working solution. WPF contains the classes PrintTicket and PrintQueue to control the output, but neither of them contain a PrintToFile (or similar) property.

Answer (score -1):

With a WPF project, System.Drawing.Printing is where PrintDocument resides.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing(v=vs.110).aspx

describes this namespace as "The System.Drawing.Printing namespace provides print-related services for Windows Forms applications."

Comment: system.drawing.printing is not for WPF.