# Windows 10 Print to PDF from command-line

Tags: batch-file, pdf, printing, windows-10

I'm correcting assignments from my students right now and I'd like to automate an annoying step I always have to do.
After annotating their PDF solutions, I need to Print them to PDF files in order to bake my annotations into the PDF so that they can be included in LaTeX. Right now I have to manually choose "Microsoft Print to PDF" and enter the PDFs name with a leading underscore (which is what my automatically generated LaTeX files expect). This gets annoying for 30+ files.
So I'd like to issue this in a batch-script automatically for all the PDFs to minimize my efforts to a simple double-click. I have seen that this is possible with e.g. C# ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896952/how-to-programmatically-print-to-pdf-file-without-prompting-for-filename-in-c-sh)), but I'd like a solution with a simple batch script.
Can this be done?

Edit:
The C#-Code I found actually does not get the Job done. You can't print *existing* PDFs that way. I'd need to use Spire.PDF to do that. The Free Version however messes up the PDF; I can download the "Full" version in NuGet, this however generates a disclaimer at the beginning of any PDF, and it still can't handle things I draw in Adobe Reader DC. So C# really is not an option, I need a command-line solution.

Comment: I mean technically you can write a batch wrapper for a PowerShell wrapper for the C# code you posted.

Comment: _Technically_, but then I'd rather simply write that C# application alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll better install [pdfcreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator)

and use the [commandline options](http://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/2.0/en/using-pdfcreator/command-line-parameters/)

Comment: This looks promising, unfortunately when I try to run it via commandline as stated in your link, I always get the error "The following files can't be converted [...]".

Comment: Okay, I got it to work by _not_ using pdfcreator's commandline options, but Acrobat Reader DC's commandline options, where I specified my custom printer I created with pdfcreator. That printer simply autosaves the file with a leading underscore. It works as expected!
`cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t C:\temp\MyPDF.pdf "MyCoolPrinter"`

Comment: How did you make your custom pdfcreator printer autosave the file with a leading underscore?

Comment: broken link for command line options, use this: https://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/en/pdfcreator/using-pdfcreator/command-line-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

I assume it should be quite easy using PowerShell, but I ran into the same problem as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65677677/7259176).
The PowerShell solution from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/04ddfe8c-a07f-4d9b-afd6-04b147f59e28/automating-printing-to-pdf?forum=winserverpowershell) creates only blank PDF files for me.

There probably exist better solutions, but I managed to combine [PDFtoPrinter](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eem36/pdftoprinter.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52486170/7259176).

A batch script could look like this:

```
for /R %%f in (*.pdf) do (
    (echo with createobject^("wscript.shell"^)
    echo .run "<path to PDFtoPrinter.exe> ""%%f"""
    echo wscript.sleep 3000
    echo .sendkeys """%%~df%%~pf%%~nf_correction.pdf"""
    echo .sendkeys "{enter}"
    echo wscript.sleep 3000
    echo end with) > %temp%\sk.vbs
    start /w %temp%\sk.vbs
)
```

This script uses `Microsoft Print to PDF` to create corresponding files of the format `<filename>_correction.pdf`.

The batch script creates an `sk.vbs` script in `%temp%` and runs it.
The `sk.vbs` script then handles the file saving dialog of `Microsoft Print to PDF`.

Additionally, this solution has the drawback that you can't use your computer while the script runs because the `sk.vbs` script must send keys to the window in focus.