# Printing programmatically in C# - avoid input request

Tags: c#, printing

I am writing a code in c# that prints PDF programmatically using printer drivers. Sometimes, it is shown a pop up that requires user input, e.g.

> The toner is about to be exhausted, continue?  YES - NO

and the printer doesn't print until the user clicks. This code runs on a server, so no one can go and click.
Is there a way to overcome this problem, without knowing all the possible questions (different printers).
I use this code to print, I block printing until previous document is printed:

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\"";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
process.Start();
var server = new PrintServer();

try
{
    int numberOfJobs = server.GetPrintQueue(printerName).NumberOfJobs;

    while (numberOfJobs == 0)
    {
        numberOfJobs = server.GetPrintQueue(printerName).NumberOfJobs;

    }
    while (numberOfJobs > 0)
    {
        numberOfJobs = server.GetPrintQueue(printerName).NumberOfJobs;
    }
    retVal = true;
}
catch
{
    retVal = false;
}
finally
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

Comment: See this : https://www.technipages.com/disable-windows-print-notification-balloon

Comment: Why do you need to print using some process? There are methods to print directly in c#, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36432772/1997232).

Comment: The fact is using "Process", you're launching an external process, which does whatever it wants. See @Sinatr comment to avoid trying to print that way.

Comment: in the @Sinatr link, it is requested or Windows 10  or Microsoft.Office.Interop. It's not ok for me

Comment: @PaulF, it's not notification balloon, but a Dialog one that stops the printing until user clicks

Comment: *"it is requested or Windows 10 or Microsoft.Office.Interop"* - what? [PrintDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) exists from stone age. And it will output on the walls of your cave if needed... or what do you mean?

Comment: @Sinatr: as far as I understand the question Valentina is trying to print PDF files, not "Print To PDF" as your first link is showing. The issue is the Toner Low dialog that appears on the print server which needs operator attention before printing can take place.