# Print to PDF with Microsoft Print to PDF printer

Tags: c#, .net, ms-project

I try to print a ms project file to pdf without any additional action needed.

I have tried several solutions without success.

```
PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument()
{
//DocumentName = safeDir + fileName,
    PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings()
    {
        // set the printer to 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
        PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",

        // tell the object this document will print to file
        PrintToFile = true,


        // set the filename to whatever you like (full path)
        PrintFileName = safeDir + fileName,
    }
};
doc.Print();
```

If i try this approach like showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896952/how-to-programmatically-print-to-pdf-file-without-prompting-for-filename-in-c-sh), I get an empty pdf file.

Manually printing to PDF works fine.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

My *Spidey Senses* tells me this is most likely caused by commas in the file name

> This is a known bug when printing to PDF. Use a different driver or
>   don't put a comma in the file name

***Note*** : Its not only from code, its in general in certain situations.

***Disclaimer*** : this is a complete and utter guess

---

**Check these other links out**

[Bug in "Print to PDF" and "Print to XPS" in Windows 10? comma in filename results in zero-byte file](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/bug-in-print-to-pdf-and-print-to-xps-in-windows-10/13e0976f-7bbe-4aec-bffe-c3cded548a49)

[Microsoft Print to PDF not working](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-winapps-appscat_tools/microsoft-print-to-pdf-not-working/45ca98f8-7df0-402e-89cc-7ae3d89aa1e8)

[Found a bug in Microsoft Print to PDF](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/found-a-bug-in-microsoft-print-to-pdf/595a2ddd-0fd0-4104-ac2c-5804cbbbaa07)

[Microsoft Print to PDF in Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/microsoft-print-to-pdf-in-windows-10/60a85085-091f-4c83-b776-e9c298aa1113)

Comment: I do not have a comma in the file name. And manually printing with the same filename works fine. Even with Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\test123.pdf" as savepath does not work. file ist only 1KB big. I can open it but it is just white. But thank you for your tip.