# how to print a pdf using microsoft print to pdf

Tags: pdf, printing, windows-10

I do not understand how to use the microsoft print to pdf in order to print a **specific** pdf file, and save it (using the microsoft print to pdf) as another pdf file.

I searched and found this issue:

[How to programmatically print to PDF file without prompting for filename in C# using the Microsoft Print To PDF printer that comes with Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896952/how-to-programmatically-print-to-pdf-file-without-prompting-for-filename-in-c-sh)

however, i do not understand where is the input pdf (i.e - the file to be printed).

I guess that's something very basic that I am searching...  help will be much appreciated!

Comment: so... i want to create a PDF (like you said, using the Microsoft printer) from another PDF file - it is not possible? does not make sense

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 includes native support for creating PDF files using Microsoft Print to PDF, a virtual printer.

ie; We can print to PDF or Save as PDF file in Windows 10 without installing any third party software.

Find below the step-by-step process to print to PDF.

1. Open the file you want to print to PDF and right click on it or open the Print menu (Ctrl +P) and select the ‘Print’ option.
2. Now you will get an option to select the Printer from a list of installed printers. Find and select ‘Microsoft Print to PDF‘ and click on ‘Print‘ button.
3. You will get an option to choose the location and click ‘OK’ to save the file. The file is saved as a brand new PDF document.

**[How to Enable and Activate the Print to PDF Feature on Windows 10](https://admeonline.com/how-to-print-to-pdf-in-windows-10-save-as-pdf-printer/)**

If Microsoft Print to PDF option is missing from the list of printers (Select Printer Option), you can Enable Microsoft Print to PDF Printer easily using any of the following methods.

1. Enable Microsoft Print to PDF on Windows Settings Page
2. Add a Printer through Devices and Printers in Control Panel
3. Enable Print to PDF  from Windows Features

Check this Post: https://admeonline.com/how-to-print-to-pdf-in-windows-10-save-as-pdf-printer/