# (C# Windows Form) Convert and Save File to PDF using Microsoft Print to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I did a windows form using C# about Conversion File to PDF using Microsoft Print to PDF. I already referred to many coding and one of it is from [Unable to open the PDF, which was generated using print to pdf code written in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586880/unable-to-open-the-pdf-which-was-generated-using-print-to-pdf-code-written-in-c).

Here below is what I made some little changes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
//using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
//using Spire.Pdf;

namespace fileConversion
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.Drawing.Font printFont;
        private StreamReader streamToPrint;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void selectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                label1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName; //text label1 tu pegang file name yang kita select
            }
        }

        private void convertFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string FileName = label1.Text;
             // the directory to store the output.
             //string directoryPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName);

            // initialize PrintDocument object
            PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument()
             {
                PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings()
                {
                   // set the printer to 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
                   PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",

                    // set the filename to whatever you like (full path)
                    PrintFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"" + FileName + ".pdf"),

                    // tell the object this document will print to file
                    PrintToFile = true,
                }
             };

             doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
             doc.Print();
        }

        private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
        {
            float linesPerPage = 0;
            float yPos = 0;
            int count = 0;
            float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
            float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
            string line = File.ReadAllText(label1.Text);

           // Calculate the number of lines per page.
           linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height /
              printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

            // Print each line of the file.
            while ((line = streamToPrint.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                yPos = topMargin + (count *
                   printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
                ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black,
                   leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
                count++;
            }

            // If more lines exist, print another page.
            if (line != null)
                ev.HasMorePages = true;
            else
                ev.HasMorePages = false;
        }
    }
}
```

However, based on what I did (above code), I successfully convert the file to pdf, but it is unable to open. Before I changed above code, I did:

```
private void convertFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string FileName = label1.Text;
             // the directory to store the output.
             //string directoryPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName);

            // initialize PrintDocument object
            PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument()
             {
                PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings()
                {
                   // set the printer to 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
                   PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",

                    // set the filename to whatever you like (full path)
                    PrintFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"" + FileName + ".pdf"),

                    // tell the object this document will print to file
                    PrintToFile = true,
                }
             };

             doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
             doc.Print();
        }
```

Though the conversion from file to pdf are success, but the contents in the pdf file are not displayed. there's only blank pdf file.

**and this is my new code after corrected.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace fileConversion
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static Font printFont;
        private static StreamReader streamToPrint;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void selectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                label1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName; //text label1 tu pegang file name yang kita select
            }
        }

        private void convertFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    streamToPrint = new StreamReader(@"" + label1.Text);
                    PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
                    if (printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName == "Microsoft Print to PDF")
                    {   // force a reasonable filename
                        string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(label1.Text);
                        string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(label1.Text);
                        doc.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
                        // confirm the user wants to use that name
                        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
                        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = directory;
                        saveFileDialog1.FileName = filename + ".pdf";
                        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF File|*.pdf";
                        result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                        if (result != DialogResult.Cancel)
                            doc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                    }

                    if (result != DialogResult.Cancel)  // in case they canceled the save as dialog
                    {
                        doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
                        doc.Print();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                streamToPrint.Close();
            }
        }

        private static void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
        {
            float linesPerPage = 0;
            float yPos = 0;
            int count = 0;
            float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
            float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
            String line = null;

            // Calculate the number of lines per page.
            linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height /
                           printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

            // Iterate over the file, printing each line.
            while (count < linesPerPage &&
            ((line = streamToPrint.ReadLine()) != null))
            {
                yPos = topMargin + (count *
                   printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
                ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black,
                   leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
                count++;
            }

            // If more lines exist, print another page.
            if (line != null)
                ev.HasMorePages = true;
            else
                ev.HasMorePages = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you haven't initialized the `streamToPrint` variable just initialize that with the file you want to be converted.

Comment: @vikscool okay, i already put that. and after i tried run the program, **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**  show up and it specified to  `linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);`

Comment: the code one that i corrected, shows what i mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: you are getting **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** because of the `printFont` variable as you have declared it but you haven't initialized it. So, it is null that's why it is throwing the error. Just initialize it as `printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);` (or define any font-family of your choice and the size) at the constructor of the `form1`.

Comment: @vikscool when i convert excel or doc file to pdf, the contents turned out to be full of symbols. but for .txt file, it turned out okay.

Comment: the `.txt` files are simple they just contain texts whereas the formatting in the `word` or `excel` file is different which when you read with them via the `StreamReader` gives you symbols (as excel files are based on row and columns). So, create a different implementation of the type that you want to convert to pdf.

Comment: @vikscool alright. Thank you so much helping me!

Comment: you are welcome.